# Upgrading Existing XCode iPhone Project to 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, ios4, xcode3.2

I upgraded xcode to 3.2.3 and loaded an existing project I had created with a prior version of xcode.  It seems to compile fine as I have set up the correct deployment target and base sdk.  When I look under Groups & Files, the Framework group, the Framework files are red and are pointing to the old framework files which don't exist anymore.

My question is should I be removing these Framework files and readding them to the project to point to the new ios4 versions of the framework?

Answer (score 0):

Steps For Upgrade Project in updated Xcode

1--> You Have To set Base Sdk From Project-->info-->build

2--> Confirm From Project under Target -->info-->build

And Compile your Project